# Cannot find function setValue in suite script 2.0?

Tags: schedule, suitescript2.0

I wrote this scheduled script to un drop-off orders from saved search, but it gives me this error:

{Cannot find function setValue in object [object Object](/SuiteScripts/searchv2.js#33)}

I got the value from the saved search but trying to update the fields is not working
the code is

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
define(['N/search','N/record', 'N/log'], function(search, record,log) {
    function execute() {
        var mySalesOrderSearch = search.load({
            id: 'customsearch1199'
        });
        var resultSet = mySalesOrderSearch.run();
        var results = resultSet.getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 });
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            printResults(results[i]);
        }

        function printResults() {
            log.debug({ title: "sales order id", details: results[i].id });
            record.setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody_sor_dropoffstatus',
                value: 'NOT_STARTED'
            }).setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody_sor_dropoffqr',
                value: ''
            }).setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody_sor_dropoffimageurl',
                value: ''
            }).setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody_sor_dropoffstarttime',
                value: ''
            }).setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody_sor_dropoffarrivetime',
                value: ''
            }).setValue({
                fieldId: 'custbody_sor_dropoffcompletetime',
                value: ''
            });
            record.save({
                enableSourcing: true,
                ignoreMandatoryFields: false
            });
            log.debug({
                title: 'Debug',
                details: 'Done' + sorId
            });
        }
        return true;
}
return {
    execute: execute
};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call setValue from a record.Record object. You can get an object by doing a load:

```
var objRecord = record.load({
    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    id: results[i].id
});
```

However, I recommend checking record.submitFields first if you are just updating body fields.